# Deleting Files Older Than 7 Days using PowerShell on Windows Server 2012

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
$PathToFolder = "D:\SCAN\iPhoneDepartment"
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToFolder -Include *.* -File -Recurse | ? {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit
}| foreach { $_.Delete()}
```

This is my code and it runs without any errors but it's not removing files that are older than 7 days.

Comment: This code definitely works, I've tried it in my own testlab.  Have you ensured that you have files older than 7 days in this folder?

Comment: I had files from 3-36-2015 which is older than 7 days.

Comment: I second *FoxDeploy*, this code works and I can't get it to break. Try and put some write-output statements in to see what is going on. Maybe "Regional Settings"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're trying to delete files that haven't changed in 7 days?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToFolder -File -Recurse | ? LastWriteTime -LE $limit | Remove-Item
```